# why having @JvmStatic but calling from java still needs 'Companion'

Tags: android, kotlin

in [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html), to call the kotlin static function in Java it could be done:

```
class C {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun foo() {}
        fun bar() {}
    }
}

C.foo(); // works fine
C.bar(); // error
C.INSTANCE.bar(); // works, a call through the singleton instance
C.INSTANCE.foo(); // works too
```

but for me it does not work without the `'companion'`,

kotlin code

```
class MyClass {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun test(category: String, otherType: OtherType) {
        ... ...
        }
    }
}
```

in JAVA code to call the static test() function,

```
MyClass.Companion.test("", OtherType())  //<== works
MyClass.test("", OtherType())  //<== error, "Cannot resolve method 'test(String, ..."
```

what else I might have missed?

Comment: Can't reproduce this... By the way your example has a mistake: you're passing `null` as non-nullable `OtherType`.

Comment: thanks @Pawel, that is just code snippet I typed in for the fail case, in real code it is not null.

Comment: In the example you are giving it should be `C.foo()`, `C.bar()` etc. instead of `Obj.foo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running into similar issue in a different project,   but after delete that project and re-clone it, then after sync the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@JvmStatic` tells the Kotlin compiler to generate a static method for the class `MyClass` therefore both `MyClass.Companion.test(...)` and `MyClass.test("", OtherType())` work.

Without `@JvmStatic` only `MyClass.Companion.test(...)` works as the compiler does not generate `MyClass.test(...)`

Comment: the question is even if with @JvmStatic it still complain about without 'Companion' part.

Comment: Does it work with a different signature for `test(...)`? For example `test(category: String, other: String)`. Maybe `OtherType` is the problem.